Microsoft Kinect controller for a threejs character: bones not moving correctly
I am working on a project to control a character in threejs using a microsoft kinect.
The data for the connect is coming in correctly, The mapping for the bones is working I guess.
But when you look at the movement in the top left - that is the kinect data mapped to points displaying a skeleton - the character is not moving the same way :slight_smile:
Video: https://global.discourse-cdn.com/flex035/uploads/threejs/original/3X/9/7/97c1c8c941aa8b2b98b22602136629070a9c9008.mov
Would someone be willing to help out/collab on this or does anyone see where I have gone wrong?
All input is much appreciated!
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <title>Kinect ThreeJS Controller</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
            }

            canvas {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            #bodyCanvas {
                z-index: 1;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="artifactCanvas"></canvas>

        <canvas id="bodyCanvas" width="512" height="424"></canvas>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fflate@0.8.2/umd/index.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

        <script>
            const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
            // Set up scene, camera, and renderer
            const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

            const scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, windowWidth / windowHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: artifactCanvas });
            renderer.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
            //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            // Add lights
            const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
            scene.add(ambientLight);
            const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
            directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 1);
            scene.add(directionalLight);

            // Set up camera position and controls
            camera.position.set(0, 100, 300);  // Adjust these values
            camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
            const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            let skeleton;

            // Load FBX model
            const fbxLoader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
            fbxLoader.load('santa.fbx', (fbx) => {
                // Try a larger scale
                //fbx.scale.setScalar(1.0);  // Adjust this value to match skeleton size
                scene.add(fbx);

                skeleton = fbx.skeleton;

                // Add skeleton helper to visualize the skeleton
                const skeletonHelper = new THREE.SkeletonHelper(fbx);
                skeletonHelper.material.linewidth = 2; // Make bones more visible
                skeletonHelper.visible = true;
                scene.add(skeletonHelper);

                // Store bone references for easier access
                const bones = {};
                const initialPositions = {};
                fbx.traverse((bone) => {
                    if (bone.isBone) {
                        const name = bone.name.toLowerCase();
                        bones[name] = bone;
                        initialPositions[name] = bone.position.clone();
                    }
                });
                // Connect to socket


                socket.on('bodyFrame', (data) => {
                    const joints = JSON.parse(data);
                    // Map Kinect joints to model bones
                    for (const jointName in joints) {
                        const joint = joints[jointName];
                        const boneName = mapJointToBone(jointName);
                        if (bones[boneName]) {
                            // Apply position relative to initial pose
                            bones[boneName].position.set(
                                initialPositions[boneName].x + joint.cameraX * 10,
                                initialPositions[boneName].y + joint.cameraY * 10,
                                initialPositions[boneName].z - joint.cameraZ
                            );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            // Helper function to map Kinect joint names to model bone names
            function mapJointToBone(jointName) {
                /*
                "mixamorigHead"
                "mixamorigHeadTop_End"
                "mixamorigHips"
                "mixamorigLeftArm"
                "mixamorigLeftFoot"
                "mixamorigLeftForeArm"
                "mixamorigLeftHand"
                "mixamorigLeftLeg"
                "mixamorigLeftShoulder"
                "mixamorigLeftToe_End"
                "mixamorigLeftToeBase"
                "mixamorigLeftUpLeg"
                "mixamorigNeck"
                "mixamorigRightArm"
                "mixamorigRightFoot"
                "mixamorigRightForeArm"
                "mixamorigRightHand"
                "mixamorigRightLeg"
                "mixamorigRightShoulder"
                "mixamorigRightToe_End"
                "mixamorigRightToeBase"
                "mixamorigRightUpLeg"
                "mixamorigSpine"
                "mixamorigSpine1"
                "mixamorigSpine2"
    
                */
                const mapping = {
                    0: 'mixamorigspine',
                    2: 'mixamorigneck',
                    3: 'mixamorighead',
                    4: 'mixamorigleftshoulder',
                    5: 'mixamorigleftarm',
                    6: 'mixamorigleftforearm',
                    7: 'mixamoriglefthand',
                    8: 'mixamorigrightshoulder',
                    9: 'mixamorigrightarm',
                    10: 'mixamorigrightforearm',
                    11: 'mixamorigrighthand',
                    12: 'mixamorigleftupleg',
                    13: 'mixamorigleftleg',
                    14: 'mixamoriglefttoe_end',
                    16: 'mixamorigrightupleg',
                    17: 'mixamorigrightleg',
                    18: 'mixamorigrighttoe_end'
                };
                return mapping[jointName] || jointName;
            }

            // Animation loop
            const clock = new THREE.Clock();

            function animate() {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                controls.update();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            // Handle window resize
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            });

            animate();



            var canvas = document.getElementById('bodyCanvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var colors = ['#ff0000', '#00ff00', '#0000ff', '#ffff00', '#00ffff', '#ff00ff'];

            // handstate circle size
            var HANDSIZE = 2;

            // closed hand state color
            var HANDCLOSEDCOLOR = "red";

            // open hand state color
            var HANDOPENCOLOR = "green";

            // lasso hand state color
            var HANDLASSOCOLOR = "blue";

            function updateHandState(handState, jointPoint) {
                switch (handState) {
                    case 3:
                        drawHand(jointPoint, HANDCLOSEDCOLOR);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        drawHand(jointPoint, HANDOPENCOLOR);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        drawHand(jointPoint, HANDLASSOCOLOR);
                        break;
                }
            }

            function drawHand(jointPoint, handColor) {
                // draw semi transparent hand cicles
                ctx.globalAlpha = 0.75;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = handColor;
                ctx.arc(jointPoint.depthX * 512, jointPoint.depthY * 424, HANDSIZE, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
                ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
            }



            socket.on('bodyFrame', function (bodyFrame) {
                bodyFrame = JSON.parse(bodyFrame);

                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                var index = 0;
                bodyFrame.forEach(function (aJoint) {

                    for (var jointType in aJoint) {
                        ctx.fillStyle = colors[index];
                        ctx.fillRect(aJoint.depthX * 512, aJoint.depthY * 424, HANDSIZE, HANDSIZE);
                    }
                    //updateElbowState(body.joints[5], body.joints[9]);
                    index++;
                });
            });

            // Add grid helper for reference
            const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(1000, 100);
            scene.add(gridHelper);

        </script>

    </body>

    </html>

